# Lint Field is never assigned with Butterknife

Tags: android, android-studio, lint, butterknife

Using Butterknife I have for example the follow code:

```
@InjectView(R.id.foo) View vFoo;
```

but when i run the lint I get the follow warnings:

```
Field is never assigned.
Can be private
```

how to tell to android studio that it is assigned and can't be private?

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio, when you analyze your code, in the "Inspection Results" window select that warning and click in the "Edit Settings" icon (to the left).
This will open the Inspections settings window (you can get there from the general settings too), and in the "Unused declaration" inspection there will be an "Options" section with a tab called "Entry points". There is a button "Configure annotations..." that will let you add annotations so all fields annotated with those annotations will be ignored by lint for this warning.

What Android Studio is actually doing is adding this in my .idea/misc.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  .
  .
  .
  <component name="EntryPointsManager">
    <entry_points version="2.0" />
    <list size="1">
      <item index="0" class="java.lang.String" itemvalue="butterknife.InjectView" />
    </list>
  </component>
  .
  .
  .
</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are not doing Butterknife.inject(this).